# What is a su(2) level k algebra

Tags: conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

What is meant by su(2) level k algebra ? Is it a lie algebra of some lie group ? What is the relation with SU(2) group. I see it in the context of quantum hall edges.
Googling and google-booking for a definition always takes me to explanations in the contexts of cft and wzw models. But what is the mathematical definition of this object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mathematical object is called the affine Kac-Moody algebra, which is sort of an infinite-dimensional generalization of the usual Lie algebra. For example, the generators $J_m^a$ of $SU(2)_k$ current algebra satisfy
$[J_m^a, J_n^b]=if^{abc}J_{m+n}^c + ikm\delta^{ab}\delta_{m+n,0}$
Here $f^{abc}$ is the structure constant of SU(2) Lie algebra, and $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. If you restrict to $m=0$, you get exactly the Lie algebra.

Comment: How is this related to the $SU(2)_k$ fusion rules defined on $0,\frac{1}{2},\cdots, \frac{k}{2}$ such that $j_1 \times j_2 = |j_1-j_2| + \cdots + \min \{ j_1+j_2, k - j_1-j_2\}$ ?

Comment: The representations of SU(2)k have this fusion rule, see e.g. sections 3.6 and 3.8 of conf.itp.phys.ethz.ch/esi-school/Lecture_notes/WZW%20models.pdf